# How to execute js in selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver

Selenium WebDriver Java

Anyone knows how to execute this script `js.executeScript("window.addEventListener('load',function(){document.getElementsByTagName('script')[1].src='google.com'})");`

or

```
js.executeScript("window.load = function()
{document.getElementsByTagName('script')[1].src='google.com'})");
```

This script return null. 
Eclipse says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at autotesting.itacademy.main(itacademy.java:58)

The main code here it is:

```
package autotesting;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntries;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

//for read and write from file
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class itacademy {

     private static WebDriver driver = null;

     public static JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();        
        driver.get("http://office.co.uk/");

        js.executeScript("window.addEventListener('load',function(){document.getElementsByTagName('script')[1].src='google.com'})");
            }}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your stacktrace...

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at autotesting.itacademy.main(itacademy.java:58)

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 Also this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: NULL
 at autotesting.itacademy.main(itacademy.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at autotesting.itacademy.main(itacademy.java:58)

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 js.executeScript return null. It's a strange because js script shouldn't return something in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize your `JavascriptExecutor`. Look here, you assign `driver` as null, then try to cast it to `JavascriptExecutor` and never initialize it:

```
private static WebDriver driver = null; // driver is null
public static JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; // js is null
```

Later, you assign `js` to `driver` and *then* initialize your driver object, here:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; // js is null
driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // driver is now an object
```

But by the time you do anything with `js`, it's still null:

```
js.executeScript("window.addEventListener('load',function({document.getElementsByTagName('script')[1].src='google.com'})"); // It's still null here!
```

You need to properly initialize your `js` object. By the way, you've already declared `js` as a class member, why are you reassigning it immediately in main?

```
public static JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; //  This line is unnecessary in main
```